# Domain Specific Language, Standard File Format

Tags: python, xml, json, standards, dsl

XML is a good file format for storing documents: content with metadata.  JSON is a good file format for storing data.

Is there an analogous file format standard which is good at encoding operations?  In other words, is there a standard file format which would be good for encoding small light-weight domain-specific languages?  What I have in mind are simple DSLs consisting of only string data and no more than a dozen simple commands.  My languages would consist of calling one command after another in a very simple manner (no conditionals or loops).

Currently, I've used XML to encode a series of operations, where each tag represents a different command.  A SAX parser dispatches each element as a function call.  It's very difficult to look at; just doesn't feel like an elegant solution.

Ideally, I'd be working in python and not writing my own parsers...trying to get the benefit of using an established standard file format.  One fallback is to use python itself, but of course I'd prefer a language-neutral standard if one is to be found.

Comment: How about a *text file*?

Comment: S-expressions come the closest to a potential universal format for DSL.

Comment: I guess I wonder why you can't use JSON?  The hierarchy could be your commands with the string data.  Could you show us how you'd do it in XML?

Comment: S-expressions with some very basic Lisp dialect (with macros!) should be fine.

Comment: Basically you are describing a simple scripting language.  There are many scripting languages from which to choose, including Python.  If you want to make it more universal, I don't understand why you can't just use JSON lists, with the convention that the first element in the list is the function and the other elements in the list are the arguments.

Comment: In XML, I'm doing a series of lines like <op arg1="" arg2="" />.  @DoxaLogos: How would you propose to write a series of command+args with JSON?  In my scribbling, it looked messier than even XML.

Comment: @D Epp, SK logic:  S-expressions look promising.  Trying to wrap my head around how to implement my DSL with it.  I guess I need pyparsing to implement the heavy lifting (parsing, function dispatch)?

Comment: @steveha : It seems you've described how to implement S-expressions, using a JSON parser to validate for me.

Answer (score 1):

If XML does the job, but readability is an issue, it might well be a good use case for [YAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML).  ([Python support](http://pyyaml.org/)).

There's a good [CodingHorror post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/05/xml-the-angle-bracket-tax.html) concerning the "XML angle-bracket tax"

Comment: Yes, part of the utility of a DSL is that it should be very easy to read & understand; and YAML would take it more in that direction.  Many of the other suggestions here solve the encoding problem, but don't really make the language any easier to read.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Qt's QML framework offers an alternate path to [DSL development](https://vperi.com/2012/06/04/custom-domain-specific-languages-with-qt-declarative-qml/) by extending the [QML language](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qdeclarativeintroduction.html) element set to include custom elements backed by C++ objects. Python bindings are available with [PySide](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Category:LanguageBindings::PySide).

Even though QML is primarily used for UI development, QML can be extended to represent any arbitrary object tree.

For example, this [snippet](http://qt.gitorious.org/pyside/pyside-examples/blobs/HEAD/examples/declarative/extending/chapter1-basics/basics.py) defines a new QML element (PieChart), which is then registered with the QML system and used in the QML language.

```
import sys
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtDeclarative import *

class PieChart (QDeclarativeItem):
   ...
```

PieChart is registered with the QML system:

```
 qmlRegisterType(PieChart, 'Charts', 1, 0, 'PieChart');
```

On the [QML](http://qt.gitorious.org/pyside/pyside-examples/blobs/HEAD/examples/declarative/extending/chapter1-basics/app.qml) (DSL) end, we can import and use PieChart:

```
import Charts 1.0
import Qt 4.7

Item {
    ...

    PieChart {
        id: aPieChart
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: 100; height: 100
        name: "A simple pie chart"
        color: "red"
    }
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I implemented a simple interpreter in Python, using S-expressions.  Parsers are easy to find online (about half a page of code) and implementing functions for the language can be made simple by use of function decorators.